# Create arrays inside array from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have strings like this :

- "831,403,746,399,745,409,752,426,764,435,775,448,781,467,780,483,776,509,826,513"
- "832,402,917,408,915,422,910,432,904,437,894,443,885,450,878,462,876,475,874,491,874,516,825,511"
- "468,297.00000762939453,434,218.00000762939453,416,230.00000762939453,409,246.00000762939453,405,264.00000762939453,400,275.00000762939453,384,282.00000762939453,374,288.00000762939453,352,297.00000762939453,369,340.00000762939453"

... and so on.

I need to format the strings and produce arrays in array like this :

**E.g.:**

```
var myArray = [
                  [831,403],
                  [746,399],
                  [745,409],
                  [752,426],
                  [764,435],
                  [775,448],
                  [781,467],
                  [780,483],
                  [776,509],
                  [826,513],
              ];
```

It is possible and how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you attempted till now? Where are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function parseToMatrix(str, rowCount = 2) {
    let numbers_array = str.split(",").map((str) => parseFloat(str));
    let matrix = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers_array.length; i += rowCount) {
        matrix.push(numbers_array.slice(i, i + rowCount));
    }

    return matrix;
}

let str =
    "831,403,746,399,745,409,752,426,764,435,775,448,781,467,780,483,776,509,826,513";
console.log(parseToMatrix(str));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).